# Break up running sum into maximum group size / length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to break up a running (ordered) sum into groups of a max value. When I implement the following example logic...

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
SELECT TOP (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 1000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS ID,
    LEFT(CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(100)),ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 30) AS Description
    INTO #t
FROM sys.objects

DECLARE @maxGroupSize INT
SET @maxGroupSize = 100

;WITH t AS (
SELECT
    *,
    LEN(Description) AS DescriptionLength,
    SUM(LEN(Description)) OVER (/*PARTITION BY N/A */ ORDER BY ID) AS [RunningLength],
    SUM(LEN(Description)) OVER (/*PARTITION BY N/A */ ORDER BY ID)/@maxGroupSize AS GroupID
FROM #t
)
SELECT *, SUM(DescriptionLength) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID) AS SumOfGroup
FROM t
ORDER BY GroupID, ID
```

I am getting groups that are larger than the maximum group size (length) of 100.

[image: Sample results]

Answer (score 0):

A recusive common table expression (`rcte`) would be one way to resolve this.

**Sample data**

Limited set of fixed sample data.

```
create table data
(
  id int,
  description nvarchar(20)
);

insert into data (id, description) values
( 1, 'qmlsdkjfqmsldk'),
( 2, 'mldskjf'),
( 3, 'qmsdlfkqjsdm'),
( 4, 'fmqlsdkfq'),
( 5, 'qdsfqsdfqq'),
( 6, 'mds'),
( 7, 'qmsldfkqsjdmfqlkj'),
( 8, 'qdmsl'),
( 9, 'mqlskfjqmlkd'),
(10, 'qsdqfdddffd');
```

**Solution**

For every recursion step evaluate (`r.group_running_length + len(d.description) <= @group_max_length`) if the previous group must be extended or a new group must be started in a `case` expression.

Set group target size to `40` to better fit the sample data.

```
declare @group_max_length int = 40;

with rcte as
(
  select d.id,
         d.description,
         len(d.description) as description_length,
         len(d.description) as running_length,
         1 as group_id,
         len(d.description) as group_running_length
  from data d
  where d.id = 1
union all
  select d.id,
         d.description,
         len(d.description),
         r.running_length + len(d.description),
         case
           when r.group_running_length + len(d.description) <= @group_max_length
           then r.group_id
           else r.group_id + 1
         end,
         case
           when r.group_running_length + len(d.description) <= @group_max_length
           then r.group_running_length + len(d.description)
           else len(d.description)
         end
  from rcte r
  join data d
    on d.id = r.id + 1
)
select r.id,
       r.description,
       r.description_length,
       r.running_length,
       r.group_id,
       r.group_running_length,
       gs.group_sum
from rcte r
cross apply ( select max(r2.group_running_length) as group_sum
              from rcte r2
              where r2.group_id = r.group_id ) gs -- group sum
order by r.id;
```

**Result**

Contains both the running group length as well as the group sum for every row.

```
id  description       description_length  running_length  group_id  group_running_length  group_sum
--  ----------------  ------------------  --------------  --------  --------------------  ---------
1   qmlsdkjfqmsldk     14                   14            1         14                    33
2   mldskjf             7                   21            1         21                    33
3   qmsdlfkqjsdm       12                   33            1         33                    33
4   fmqlsdkfq           9                   42            2          9                    39
5   qdsfqsdfqq         10                   52            2         19                    39
6   mds                 3                   55            2         22                    39
7   qmsldfkqsjdmfqlkj  17                   72            2         39                    39
8   qdmsl               5                   77            3          5                    28
9   mqlskfjqmlkd       12                   89            3         17                    28
10  qsdqfdddffd        11                  100            3         28                    28
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9a9c5eb08d2a1aef473c9a7a9abf2b7&hide=2) to see things in action (includes random data version).